# Randomly Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have some webserver which use to host an openx banner system
Recently I found that the error log told me there are some error - **Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket** while the peak time, but it is randomly, not always, sometime it works normal and sometime it throws this error.

any idea?

Comment: too many connections to mysql perhaps...

Comment: the error message for too many connections is too many connection

Answer (score 0):

increase the values found here `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`. By doing `echo "200" > /proc/sys/fs/file-max`

Also make sure you increase the user limits: `ulimit -n`